# TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

however, I have define the 'orders' array in my `initialState`.

Does somebody know the reason?

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes.js';
import { updateObject } from '../utility.js';

const initialState = {
    orders: [],
    loading: false,
    purchased: false
};

const purchaseInit = (state, action) => {
    return updateObject(state, { purchased: false });
};

const purchaseBurgerStart = (state, action) => {
    return updateObject(state, { loading: true });
};

const purchaseBurgerSuccess = (state, action) => {
    const newOrder = updateObject(action.orderData, { id: action.orderId });
    return updateObject(state, {
        loading: false,
        purchased: true,
        orders: state.orders.concat(newOrder)
    });
};

const purchaseBurgerFail = (state, action) => {
    return updateObject(state, { loading: false });
};

const fetchOrdersStart = (state, action) => {
    return updateObject(state, { loading: true });
};

const fetchOrdersSuccess = (state, action) => {
    return updateObject(state, {
        orders: action.orders,
        loading: false
    });
};

const fetchOrdersFail = (state, action) => {
    return updateObject(state, { loading: false });
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.PURCHASE_INIT: return purchaseInit(state, action);
        case actionTypes.PURCHASE_BURGER_START: return purchaseBurgerStart(state, action);
        case actionTypes.PURCHASE_BURGER_SUCCESS: return purchaseBurgerSuccess(state, action);
        case actionTypes.PURCHASE_BURGER_FAIL: return purchaseBurgerFail(state, action);          
        case actionTypes.FETCH_ORDERS_START: return fetchOrdersStart(state, action);
        case actionTypes.FETCH_ORDERS_SUCCESS: return fetchOrdersSuccess(state, action);
        case actionTypes.FETCH_ORDERS_FAIL: return fetchOrdersFail(state, action);       
        default: return { state };
    }
};

export default reducer;
```

Comment: please edit your code write properly for understanding

Comment: Please - provide a codepen with some more code. It will be much easier to help

Comment: how do you call `purchaseBurgerSuccess()`? What data do you pass into the first argument?

Comment: I think, you have to assign the state = initialState

Answer (score 0):

1) This line...

```
case actionTypes.PURCHASE_BURGER_SUCCESS: return purchaseBurgerSuccess(state, action);
```

...as with all the other lines in that `switch` statement should be returning a *new state*.

So in `purchaseBurgerSucess` you need to make sure you're returning a new state using the state you're passing in as an argument:

```
const purchaseBurgerSuccess = (state, action) => {
  const newOrder = updateObject(action.orderData, { id: action.orderId });

  // Spread out the state you pass in as an argument
  // and update those properties that have changed
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    purchased: true,
    orders: state.orders.concat(newOrder)
  };
};
```

Note: your other functions fall into this trap too so those will also need to be updated.

2) Your `default` case in your `switch` statement should be:

```
default: return state;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the state parameter this parameter does not have a state array, you can use a console.log to check what this parameter has.

Comment: It says that it is (orders: []) - undefined. I've tried to initialize the array with some data, but it's still 'undefined'.

Comment: When you call that function the state in an empty object try to set the state = initialState, if some on call it with an empty object it use the initial state values

Answer (score 0):

**I think you are missing to assign the state as initial state in the parameter.**

const purchaseBurgerSuccess = (state = initialState, action)